# Running meteor-mocha-chai tests on CI

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to run my meteor app's tests on Codeship CI, but without luck. I don't have any UI tests, I'm just testing the functionality of some Meteor methods. All the tests run locally successfully, but I can't find a proper way to kick off tests on CI.

Anyone knows any good links or setup on how I can achieve this?

If needed, I can change CI.

Comment: You should be able to set up git integration, so that every checkin triggers a CI run - have you done this?

Comment: Yes, I have. The issue is not to run the CI build, but what would be the command that would work that would run the tests and approve/deny build based on whether the tests pass or fail.

Comment: So I think you are looking to set up a webhook in github, so it will trigger a CI build?

Comment: No, the CI build is being executed. I just don't have any test command in there, so it succeeds because it doesn't run any tests. I'm wondering if there's anyone who managed to setup to run meteor tests on CI. That's all. How to run meteor tests on CI. There's not much in the official documentation and I didn't manage to make it work: https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html (I use practicalmeteor:chai and practicalmeteor:mocha)

Comment: I haven't used codeship, but presumably this is where you set up your test commands: https://documentation.codeship.com/basic/quickstart/getting-started/#configuring-your-test-commands

Comment: The issue is not setting up the codeship, the issue is that I don't know what command, shell command, as if I'd be running my tests in the console, I need to run for tests to execute. It's CI independent. Think of it as a .sh script. What do I need to put there so that my tests run? Currently my tests run when I open http://localhost:4000/ but not in the console. I tried passing --once param, but that doesn't make the tests run.

Comment: When you say you can run the tests locally is that with the `meteor test` command? You can put an entry in your package.json so that you can run `npm run test` - but I have a feeling that's not what you want. Do you want to kick off the CI tests from a shell script?